Finding error when use conditional statement in DAX in powerbi
The think I want to classify a numerical variable named, "customer_age" to "AgeGroup". But when I use switch statement in new measure then it gives a message that, the column "Customer_age is not located".

The DAX QUERY IS:
AgeGroup = SWITCH(
TRUE(),
'public cust_detail'[customer_age] < 30, "20-30",
'public cust_detail'[customer_age] >= 30 && 'public cust_detail'[customer_age] < 40, "30-40",
'public cust_detail'[customer_age] >= 40 && 'public cust_detail'[customer_age] < 50, "40-50",
'public cust_detail'[customer_age] >= 50 && 'public cust_detail'[customer_age] < 60, "50-60",
'public cust_detail'[customer_age] >= 60, "60+",
"unknown"
)

Note: the data is imported to power bi via Postgres SQL server on my local host.
I want to create a new measure which classify the variable customer_age to AgeGroup

I think you are creating a measure. You can try this DAX to create a calculated column

if you can to create a measure try this
    AgeGroup = SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    max('public cust_detail'[customer_age]) < 30, "20-30",
    max('public cust_detail'[customer_age]) >= 30 && max('public cust_detail'[customer_age]) < 40, "30-40",
   max( 'public cust_detail'[customer_age] )>= 40 && max('public cust_detail'[customer_age]) < 50, "40-50",
   max( 'public cust_detail'[customer_age] )>= 50 && max('public cust_detail'[customer_age]) < 60, "50-60",
    max('public cust_detail'[customer_age]) >= 60, "60+",
    "unknown"
    )

